# Can't compile .deb packages; make package command returns error

Tags: objective-c, ios, compiler-errors, debian, dpkg

When I try to compile a Notification Center widget for iOS 5 using

```
cd <name>
make package
```

then I get the following error:

```
make package requires dpkg-deb.
make: *** [package] Error 1
```

But I have installed dpkg-deb using

```
sudo su
<enter your password>
cd /bin
curl http://debmaker-osx.googlecode.com/svn-history/r5/trunk/dpkg-deb > dpkg-deb
```

And I have navigated to the `/bin` directory and the dpkg-deb file exists in the folder. What can I do to make it work? I have followed this tutorial on how to install theos, dpkg-deb and how to create a WeeAppPlugin, I'm just stuck at compiling the bundle... http://weeplugins.com/blog/?p=1

Update:
It seems like I cannot access the /bin/dpkg-deb file if I run this command

```
cd /bin/dpkg-deb
```

I get an error that I don't have permission to access the file. Is it possible to maybe move the file to another folder so that i can access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do "sudo make package". This will give you superuser permissions.

Comment: I guess the problem is not in the permissions.You can try installing dpkg on your mac. http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=dpkg.

Comment: cheers, mac ports helped. But now, i get the following error: /bin/sh: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2: No such file or directory    I just have iOS 5 sdk installed not 4.2!

Comment: you can try installing the xcode tools for this version and after that use "sudo gcc_select 4.2".

Comment: I already fixed the problem. It seems like with the new Xcode the files have been renamed, there was a file called somethingg++-4.2 and i just dublicated it and named it g++-4.2. Now everything works fine! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Along with MacPorts I also had to install the Xcode command line tools and Fink http://www.finkproject.org/